# Visual Assist Automated installation for multiple versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-assist

I would like to know how we can modify the automated installation process to allow the installation of VA in all versions of Visual Studio. Is there a specific value or parameter that needs to be added into the .inf file on the line following line: `"VA_X_Setup2488_0.exe" /S /D?`
that can be comparable to the step of manual installation that asks:

Select which IDEs you want to install to:

1. VS 2019
2. VS 2022
3. ....

Manually I have no problems but when it is an unattended installation, it only installs on one version of Visual Studio.